# Time-release Protocol Implementation

Tags: protocol-design, reference-request, timed-release

[“How to Build Time-Lock Encryption” by Jager](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/478.pdf)

[“Time-release Protocol from Bitcoin and Witness Encryption for SAT” by Liu, Garcia, and Ryan](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/27b7/5334bba2ab09e86f7b2d81af9ebc08a25de5.pdf)

I looked through the references, googled, searched GitHub but couldn't find an implementation of either of them in any programming language.

Are these theoretical with no implementation yet?

I would greatly appreciate a link to an implementation if one exists.

Comment: did you ask the author?

Comment: That was the other thing I thought of other than asking here. I am writing the emails now :)

Comment: Could whoever downvoted it explain why, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tibor Jager (author to the first paper linked in question):

> "There is no implementation yet. Given that there are no really efficient Witness Encryption schemes yet, the construction so far is rather theoretical."

Comment: Is this scheme also can't be implemented by the witness encryption which based on the indistinguishable obfuscation?If the multilinear based witness encryption can't provide the efficient required for the time-lock encryption.